# Adding Submodule Paths in a Vite React Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, vite

I have a Vite-based React library, currently structured like this:

```
import { Button, Typography, Box, Flex, Color, TypographyVariant } from '@placeholder-library';
```

I want to separate the imports to add submodules so that components and shared are imported from different paths:

```
import { Button, Typography, Box, Flex } from '@placeholder-library/components’;
import { Color, TypographyVariant } from ‘@placeholder-library/shared’;
```

**index.ts**

```
import './index.scss';
export * from './components';
export * from './shared';
```

**vite.config.ts:**

```
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import path from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts';
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import commonjs from 'vite-plugin-commonjs';

export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      src: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    },
  },
  build: {
    outDir: 'build',
    lib: {
      entry: './src/index.ts',
      name: 'Placeholder Library',
      fileName: 'index',
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
      output: [
        {
          globals: {
            react: 'React',
            'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
          },
        },
        {
          dir: 'build/cjs',
          format: 'cjs',
          globals: {
            react: 'React',
            'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
          },
        },
        {
          dir: 'build/esm',
          format: 'esm',
          globals: {
            react: 'React',
            'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    sourcemap: true,
    emptyOutDir: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    svgr(),
    react(),
    commonjs(),
    tsconfigPaths(),
    dts({
      outDir: ['build/cjs', 'build/esm', 'build'],
      include: ['./src/**/*'],
      exclude: ['**/*.stories.*'],
    }),
  ],
});
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "@placeholder-library",
  "version": "0.0.26",
  "description": "Placeholder Library components library",
  "license": "ISC",
  "main": "build/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "build/index.mjs",
  "files": ["*"],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build",
    "build-storybook-docs": "storybook build --docs",
    "dev": "vite",
    "format": "prettier --write .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --fix --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "storybook-docs": "storybook dev --docs"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "..."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "..."
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

my folder structure:
My folder structure

```
src
    index.ts
    components
        index.ts
        Button
            index.ts
    shared
        hooks
        index.ts
```

index.ts in components:

```
export * from './Button'
```

How can I configure Vite and my package structure to achieve this separation of components and shared/utils? Any advice or examples would be greatly appreciated.

I attempted to modify the **`vite.config.ts`** file to include separate entries for components and shared/utils, but I couldn't figure out how to properly configure the paths. I also tried to adjust the **`package.json`** file to specify different entry points for components and shared/utils, but I wasn't sure how to structure it correctly.

`import { Button, Typography, Box, Flex } from '@placeholder-library/components’;`

`import { Color, TypographyVariant } from ‘@placeholder-library/shared’;`

However, I couldn't find a clear example or documentation on how to set this up in a Vite-based React library. Any guidance or examples on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your project? `entry` can also be an object and you can use `exports` in your package.json to expose the different entry points.

Comment: Could you clarify what are submodules? Are they the same npm package but in different folders? And what is the problem with 2 import statements that you are using?

Comment: @morganney unfortunately I can't add this library, what files do you need? I can add

Comment: @quyentho that's what I want to achieve. now I can import only with the full path without submodules, when i try @placeholder-library/components / @placeholder-library/shared it not find the imports

Comment: @Manspof Is it possible to share the @placeholder package name? Is it your own code or a private package? Because I believe this can be easily achieved by create 2 index.js files in `/shared` and `/components` folders to export everything you need.

Comment: @quyentho it's my private package of the company, I really can't share github link so I changed.. let me know what files you need or anything I can try to add

Comment: @Manspof If you have access to change code in that private repo, simply add 2 index.js files in each folder. Then in each index.js file, you `export * from "./file-in-that-modules.js"`. Then, you can import each component using the folder names.

Comment: If you don't have access to that private repo. You can still do the trick by re-export the modules in your own code, but now the path gonna be e.g `import {Button} from '@yourcode/components'`. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: @quyentho yes I have an access to code, I wrote this library.. I already have those index files for each folder then in the first index.js I export both of them.. I think the change should be in the package.json entry and exports and not into the code/folder structure..

Comment: Sorry but I think you did it incorrectly. Could you share the index.js files in `@placeholder-lib/components` and `@placeholder-lib/shared`?

Comment: Yes I added in my post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257303/discussion-between-manspof-and-quyentho).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a demo would be easier than going back and forth: https://github.com/quyentho/submodule-demo

You can check my `dist/` folder in the `placeholder-lib` to see if your generated build has similar structure. I have no problem to import like this in my `consumer`:

```
import { Button } from "placeholder-lib/components";
import useMyHook from "placeholder-lib/shared";
```

I guess, your problem could be missing these export lines in `package.json`

```
  "exports": {
    ".": "./dist/index.js",
    "./components": "./dist/components/index.js",
    "./shared": "./dist/shared/index.js"
  },
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @quyentho ! Your solution was exactly what I needed, and the code example you provided was clear and worked perfectly. I really appreciate your expertise and the time you took to assist me. You've made a big difference in my project! 